# losing mvc intellisense

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, intellisense

My intellisense doesn't work in aspx or ascx pages running mvc 1.0
When I save or build it does not show the intellisense, but if I do a clean then it works
it this a bug or am I missing something ?

thanks

Comment: Got the same problem. It's weird.

Comment: Same thing! Do a clean and rebuild and reloading the view usually works.

Answer (score 0):

Mayby you already try it, but have you tried to click ctrl + space when writing code, that make apear intellisence when you coding.

I need to use it sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a [reset of settings](http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/50857.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+RickStrahl+%28Rick+Strahl%27s+WebLog%29) worked for me.

Still no Intellisence inside of href-target-strings though, but I guess that's not suppose to work in current version.

Comment: your link is for vs2010 beta, i'm using vs 2008. it might work but i can't really know because my intellisense came back a while ago. It went away for no apparent reason and came back the same way. If it goes away again I will test your solution.